# Manage two shortcode within same page using custom plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have created two custom shortcode in a page. How i need to enable the shortcode based on the condition in wordpress?

In my custom plugin file i have used two short code like

```
function develop_form(){
 ......
}
add_shortcode('develop', 'develop_form');
function develop2_form(){
 ......
}
add_shortcode('develop2', 'develop2_form');
```

I have created one page called "developer" in wordpress admin 
and added two shortcode within same page like [develop] and [develop2]
how to activate one short code at a time using the condition in my plugin page

Comment: Set an option within your plugin and check the option in each shortcode to determine whether that shortcode should do whatever it is supposed to do.

Comment: @Jrod thanks Jrod, please tell me how to add that option in my plugin. My scenario is i need to check the condition according to the API result not a custom field otherwise an option

Comment: Why not just check the API result within your shortcodes?

Comment: @Jrod can u clearly explain about this.

Comment: Here's a pastebin http://pastebin.com/GSGmVCZ1 with a rough example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a new field to options table

and have 1 Wordpress admin page that controls the value of that setting via checkbox

and in your plugin code you will just wrap your function with a if statement for that setting value after u queue it.

`if (get_option(your_option_name)){ then do function }`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option